# Trisecting an angle with a compass and 2 marks on a ruler

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, angle, geometric-construction

It's well known that there is no possibility to trisect and angle with a compass and a ruler.
But there is such a procedure when the ruler has 2 marks on it. See the snippet below. It's not
very intuitive but probably correct since the source is trustful: *RJ Lipton: P vs. NP and the Godel's lost letter.* I'm curious about a reference which gives this extended tools trisection.
Or even proof at this place.

[image]

Comment: Any such construction will probably involve some weird kind of neusis (in particular, laying the ruler through a given point such that both marks lie on given lines).

Comment: @Magma OK. I would bet that this construction has been studied in depth and there is a research paper on it.

Comment: I looked it up and I found Archimedes' Trisection of an Angle. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Can you please give me a reference ?

Comment: I found it here: [Url](https://study.com/academy/lesson/how-to-construct-an-angle-trisection.html)

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Correct! I just need to study this.